# Spring Batch skip job execution if job with same parameters (but different date/time) in progress

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Some of jobs run longer then our scheduler interval. It is pretty safe to skip such jobs. How can I detect if job with same name and parameters (except running time) is currently running?

Quartz run Batch jobs as:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;

@Override
protected void executeInternal(org.quartz.JobExecutionContext context) {
    Map<String, Object> jobDataMap = context.getMergedJobDataMap();
    String jobName = (String) jobDataMap.get("job.name");

    JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    builder.addString("company", jobDataMap.get("company"));
    builder.addDate("run.date", new Date());

    try {
        jobLauncher.run(jobLocator.getJob(jobName), jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
    }
    catch (JobExecutionException e) {
        log.error("Could not execute job.", e);
    }
}
```

I need to find if any Executions for specific `"job.name"`/`"company"` (regardless `"run.date"`) is running.

I can do that with plain SQL running against `BATCH_` tables.

Check supposed to run in Tasklet so [JobRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/JobRepository.html) can be autowired. Is it possible to find out only with `JobRepository` or other Spring Batch beans?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the "run.date" from identifying.

Use public `JobParameter(Date parameter, boolean identifying)`

From docs of JobParameter.

> The identifying flag is used to indicate if the parameter is to be
>   used as part of the identification of a job instance.

So just add the parameter without `builder.addDate("run.date", new Date());` and run the job.

Comment: Can I have 2 jobs for the same company (the only identifying parameter) if I ignore run date/time?

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on `JobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions()` (to find latest unfinished job):

```
/**
 * If there are jobs with same parameters, that started later then some number we can run new job again.
 *
 * {@link JobExplorer#findRunningJobExecutions(String)} selects jobs with BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.END_TIME is null.
 *
 * @return  null if there is no jobs with same parameters, otherwise the latest running.
 */
public JobExecution getLatestRunningJob(JobExplorer jobExplorer, String jobName, String agency, String branch) {
    long now = new Date().getTime();
    long minDiff = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    JobExecution latestExecution = null;
    Set<JobExecution> runningJobs = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
    for (JobExecution execution : Optional.ofNullable(runningJobs).orElse(Collections.emptySet())) {
        JobParameters params = execution.getJobParameters();
        // log.warn("agencyName {}", params.getString("agencyName"));
        // log.warn("branchName {}", params.getString("branchName"));
        if ( ! agency.equals(params.getString("agencyName")))
            continue;
        if ( ! branch.equals(params.getString("branchName")))
            continue;
        // log.warn("create {}", execution.getCreateTime());
        // log.warn("start {}", execution.getStartTime());

        long diff = now - execution.getCreateTime().getTime();
        if (diff < 0) {
            log.warn("Impossible, new job executed before old! Old JobExecution id: {}", execution.getJobId());
            continue;
        }
        if (diff < minDiff) {
            minDiff = diff;
            latestExecution = execution;
        }
    }
    return latestExecution;
}
```

and decision maker:

```
/**
 * @param execution  not null
 * @param limitMinutes  how long job should be runnning to ignore
 */
public boolean canIgnoreLateJob(JobExecution execution, long limitMinutes) {
    long now = new Date().getTime();
    long diffMinutes = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(now - execution.getCreateTime().getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (diffMinutes < limitMinutes) {
        log.warn("Recent JobExecution {} is still not finished, can't run new job, diff (minute): {}",
                execution.getJobId(), diffMinutes);
        return false;
    } else {
        log.warn("Very old JobExecution {} is still not finished, can run new job, diff (minute): {}",
                execution.getJobId(), diffMinutes);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Drawback of this solution is that `JobExplorer` resolve every field in JobExecution (including all Steps). So performance is not perfect. But solution is reliable.